# Installing Hdf4 conversion tool doesn't work

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04, libjpeg, hdf, netcdf4

Im new here as well as to install software from the source.

I want to install http://www.hdfeos.org/software/h4cflib.php to convert hdf --> netcdf files.

External requirements are HDF4 HDF-EOS2 libraries.

So I 1st checked with

```
dpkg -l | grep hdf
ii  libhdf4-0-alt 4.2.10-3.2 amd64 Hierarchical Data Format library (without NetCDF)
ii  libhdf5-10:amd64                           1.8.16+docs-4ubuntu1                           amd64        Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - runtime files - serial version
```

Thus I assumed to have libhdf4 without netcdf installed (see the hint on eos instructions: HDF4 library must be configured with "--disable-netcdf" option.)

2nd for hdf-eos nothing found in the same way. So tried to install this, from:
https://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/TKDownload.html --> hdfeos --> latest_release --> HDF-EOS2.19v1.00.tar.Z
and followed user guide from the same folder: HDF-EOS_UG.pdf

install-script section (Appendix A.1.3.1):

```
zcat HDF-EOS2.19v1.00.tar.Z | tar xvf -
cd hdfeos
bin/INSTALL-HDFEOS -sgi64
Error: In 64-bit linux platform the env. variable LINUX_BRAND must be set to linux32 or linux64 before running this script.
```

Installation Using Autoconf/Automake (Appendix A.1.3.2):

```
cd [...]/hdfeos
./configure --with-hdf=/usr/lib/libmfhdfalt.so.0 --libdir=[...]/hdfeos/lib/linux
[...]
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking for ceil in -lm... yes
checking for jpeg_set_defaults in -ljpeg... no
configure: error: couldn't find jpeg library
```

Here I did /usr/lib/libmfhdfalt.so.0 because I found:

```
ldconfig -p | grep hdf
libmfhdfalt.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmfhdfalt.so.0
```

But problem seems here to be jpeg library anyway.

```
ldconfig -p | grep jpeg
libjpeg.so.9 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.9
libjpeg.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8

dpkg -l | grep jpeg
ii  libjpeg-turbo8:amd64                       1.4.2-0ubuntu3                                 amd64        IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
ii  libjpeg8:amd64                             8c-2ubuntu8                                    amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libjpeg9:amd64                             1:9b-1ubuntu1                                  amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library
```

Tried also to install it from source. Found in the eos folder on: jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz

```
cd jpeg-6b/
./configure
make    
sudo make install
```

works without errors apart from me having to manually create a folder.

So I try again to install:

```
cd [...]/hdfeos
./configure --with-hdf=/usr/lib/libmfhdfalt.so.0 --with-jpeg=/usr/local/bin/ --libdir=[...]/hdfeos/lib/linux
    [...]
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking for ceil in -lm... yes
checking for jpeg_set_defaults in -ljpeg... no
configure: error: couldn't find jpeg library
```

for the install scritpt method:
what to do about this LINUX_BRAND variable?

for the autoconf/automake way:
Do I have wrong path to the jpeg library? If so how do I find the path?
Is there something wrong in general with proceeding?

I don't really know what to read or to google. Sorry if the quesion is not properly posed, I will learn if you correct me.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't need a solution here anymore. Figured out that the binariy executable  version for CentOs works for me, I didn't know and try that.

If someone still wants to give a short explanation about installation of libraries: how to find out if and where installed and how to pass the latter information to a configure command, I would be glad to know! Thanks.